# Configuration error when installing R on Linux

Tags: linux, r

Steps to install:

1. ./configure --enable-R-shlib

I get this error:

```
 configure: error: --with-x=yes (default) and X11 headers/libs are not available
```

in config.log file
I see this entry:

```
 #define X_DISPLAY_MISSING 1
```

any ideas?

Comment: Depending on what distribution you're running, and whether you need to compile from source for some particular reason, you could also consider installing a binary package -- see the notes on CRAN.

Comment: The `--enable-R-shlib` option is already the default on several Linux distributions (including Debian and its derivatives Ubuntu etc). So as Ben suggests, why not use a binary?

Comment: alternatively, if you insist on compiling from source and are on a debian derivative, you could use `apt-get build-dep` to make sure everything you need for R is present.

Comment: I really like richie's comment - the full command line is "apt-get build-dep r-base".

Comment: You could post this as an answer, for me this solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try either passing --with-x=no to the configure script, or install the X devel package for your linux flavour.

Comment: or even better, install xorg-dev and libreadline-dev

Comment: passing =no would turn R unusable with a GUI/graphics, just a comment in case someone opt for this 'solution'